# The bullying he had received?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In the following question, I need a verb (past participle):

Was the student questioned about bullying he had ______ ?

I realize one could say *been subjected to*, but that feels stilted to me.

"been on the receiving end of" has the right tone but I need something simpler.

Edit 8/31/16: I need something more emotionally neutral for my purposes.  "Experienced" seems to be working reasonably well so far.

Comment: The sentence in your question is missing a definite article: it should have "the" before "bullying," like in the title.

Comment: If a better option doesn't turn up, I guess I'll say "bullying he experienced".

Comment: @suməlic - Using "the" implies that bullying has definitely occurred.  "Was the student questioned about bullying he had experienced?" would not imply this so strongly, and saying "Was the student questioned about any bullying he had experienced?" (or "he might have experienced") would imply even less.

Comment: This is weak compared to the other suggestions, but: the bullying he had *encountered*.

Comment: "Was the student questioned about being bullied?"

Comment: @Jordan.J.D - that's pretty good!  I think I would modify it a bit for my purposes, "Wast the student questions about having been bullied?"

Comment: Oops!  Let's try that again.  @Jordan.J.D - that's pretty good! I think I would modify it a bit for my purposes, "Was the student questioned about having been bullied?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The student was questioned about bullying he had *experienced*.

I like this because it's emotionally neutral.

Answer (score 5):

[Endure](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/endure) — to suffer something difficult, unpleasant, or painful — is a good match, and plenty of examples turn up online of it being used with "bullying" in just this way.

Here's one example from [*The Chattanoogan*](http://www.chattanoogan.com/2016/8/18/330161/Roy-Exum-Bullying-Causes-This.aspx):

> In his pocket was a letter written to those at the Holy Angels Catholic Academy that told, in the most heart-wrenching way you can imagine, about **the horrible bullying he had endured** the school year before, the constant taunting, and that “he gave up.”

So:

> Was the student questioned about [the] bullying he had **endured**?

Answer (score 3):

Most people would say "Was the student questioned about any bullying he had **suffered**?

> [**suffer**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/suffer) - (verb)  "to experience, undergo, or feel (something painful, injurious, or unpleasant)

One can suffer

- a terrible loss, a blow, a nervous breakdown
- a heart attack, a stroke, an injury
- an accident, humiliation, a defeat, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Since I offered a quick solution as a comment and OP liked it, I will post it as an answer:

> "Was the student questioned about being bullied?"